# How to connect and transfer file between two computers in different ISP using python?

Tags: python, tcp, sftp

I was wondering what will be the best pythonic (preferably free, not interested in paid cloud servers) way to communicate between two computers in different ISP? I have a couple of videos which I want to transfer to another machine in entirely different ISP and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

There are two sides involved firstly the server side. Its hard to code it here in limited space but the server will be hosting while you will be making a client computer which will be transmitting the data which can done directly by using `open()` to open the file and then transfer it over a network.

So,

Step 1: establishing the connection use library like `socket` to do so

Step 2: open the required file and send it over the network

Step 3: Terminate the session

[You can refer to the following link to get the idea](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/send-receive-files-using-sockets-python)

Comment: I think you are mentioning file transfer in the same network, wi-fi connection or LAN?

Comment: yes but you can do it over internet too. condition you need to have the network configuration.

Comment: @Arunabh, can you elaborate a bit, the link you gave was for the same network. However I have been looking into port forwarding options.